# turning a jquery function into a normal function

Tags: jquery

I inserted some jquery code which is designed for an feature of one page into my common js file. Now all pages are throwing an error and I think it is because I don't understand the difference between a jQuery function and a normal one.
The jQuery one starts off like this:

```
$.fn.googleMap = function(address, options) {
```

and is called from within the $(document).ready(function(){ like this:

```
$("#location div").removeClass().googleMap(""+location1+"");
```

I tried (just in case) to do: function googleMap(address, options) { ...but then I am not sure if that 1. works and 2. how to trigger it from within "$(document).ready" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extract the jquery function into a separate file and include it in the pages where you are calling the method as with other jquery plugins.

Comment: I've done what you've said and it seems to be working but in theory it shouldn't have because of the load order I have had to put it in. You see, the site has global includes which makes it hard - I will indicate the global files with the dashed line:
--------
1. jquery-1.3.1.min.js
2. jquery.common.js (has the call to googleMap function in it
--------
3. google map API
4. jquery.googlemap.js

It may be why I am now getting this on every page in firebug:
$("#location div").r...ap is not a function

Comment: Is it a matter of pulling 3 & 4 into #2? How would I suck in javascript from a javascript file?

Comment: Yes you will have to include the **googleMap.js** file before your **jquery.common.js** file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end I made another $(document).ready function in the jquery.googleMap.js file and thus enabled everything to load in the correct order. I forgot you could have 2 document ready functions, your last message prompted me.